# Negation of a simple sentence, but confusing one

Tags: logic

What is the negation of

> I ride or drive *every day*.

Is the following one correct?

> I **neither** ride **nor** drive *every day*

or

> I ride **or** drive **not** *every day*.

Are there any way to express negation of "*every day*"?

Like "*someday*" or "*some day*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `R(d)` be the proposition "I ride/rode on day `d`", and `D(d)` the same for driving.  Then the statement "I ride or drive every day" can be expressed as `∀ d : R(d) ∨ D(d)`.  Negating this just gives `¬(∀ d : R(d) ∨ D(d))`.

Language does not always give you a convenient form in which to state your logical formulas.  In English, the preferred form would be "It is not the case that I ride or drive every day."  (You need all of "It is ... the case that" to make it clear that the "not" is modifying everything else you're saying--it serves, by virtue of length and custom, the same role as the parentheses.  Note that there are not very *many* levels of parentheses that you can effectively convey in English prose this way--this is one reason why people use mathematical notation for logic.  But here, it suffices.  Merely, "I do not ride or drive every day" may also work, but it could also be parsed as "I do not ride every day and I do not drive every day", which is a different statement.)

However, since you are trying to express a logical formula, you can always use identities to transform your logical statement into a form whose English (or other language) representation feels more natural.  For instance, using the identity `¬∀x p(x) iff ∃x ¬p(x)`, an equivalent statement is `∃ d : ¬(R(d) ∨ D(d))`.  The English version of this is "Some days I neither ride nor drive."  (The existential mapping to "some", and the negation of an "or" mapping to the "neither/nor" structure.)

Note that in English, the implication of "some days" is that there are other days that are different. If you said "some days it rains" but it actually rains every day, it would be technically correct but the listener would feel justifiably misled.  Almost every phrasing carries some impliciation like this, though: "there has been a day where I neither rode nor drove" suggests such days are rare; "it is not the case that I always ride or drive" suggests that riding or driving is the norm; "sometimes I avoid driving and avoid riding" again suggests rarity; "usually I drive or ride" suggests that sometimes (rarely) you do one but occasionally none; "usually I avoid riding and avoid driving" suggests that you sometimes must do at least one but usually don't.  Language is rich with implicature, and if you wish to avoid this, you generally must stick with logical formalism.

Answer (score 1):

This should really go into ell.stackexchange.com (English learners)... You are asking about English sentences.

"I neither ride nor drive every day" is usually parsed "I do not ride every day, and I also do not drive every day"; it is a shortcut for "I neither ride every day, nor do I drive every day". Which is not the negation of the original sentence, because if you ride every monday to friday, and you driver every saturday or sunday, both statements are true.

"I ride or drive not every day" is usually parsed as "Huh? ". I wouldn't know what you mean by it.

"I do not ride or drive every day" would be parsed as the opposite of the original statement. Again, we are talking about English language and English sentences here, and not about logic.

The negation of "every day" is "not every day" - but you have to built this properly into English sentences.

Comment: I have a book named "How to prove it. Velleman". There are similiar quetions in chapter one.